# How to select this element using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<nav class="myNav">
 <ul>
   <li>foo</li>
   <li>bar</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

I would like to select the second li element (the one with "bar" in it) using Jquery.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$('.myNav ul li:eq(1)')` which will give you the second li element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myNav ul li:nth-child(2)')
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pw8LF/)

Answer (score 0):

`$('nav.myNav > ul > li:eq(1)')`

http://jsfiddle.net/Fsnjq/